# How should I use git rebase to remove duplicate commits introduced by git cherry-pick?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I'm a bit confused by `git rebase`.

I have a `develop` branch and a `staging` branch. I've merged `develop` into `staging`

```
git checkout staging
git merge develop
```

But there are a bunch of duplicate commits because of cherry picks; I want to remove the duplicates. Should I do the following?

```
git checkout staging
git rebase develop
```

UPDATE: The `git merge develop` is local, so I haven't pushed it yet

Comment: You'll need to look into `git rebase -i` (interactive). However, it is not advised to rebase a branch (or the part of it) that has already been pushed: you should only rebase purely local commits that have not been shared yet. A good introductory article is http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is: yes, rebase will squash your duplicate commits. Specifically, it will drop the cherry-picked commits, if the same commit exists in the *staging* branch.

However, I'd suggest to rebase your *develop* branch, and after that merge it to *staging*, i.e.

```
git checkout develop
git rebase staging
git checkout staging
git merge develop
```

It's better practice to rebase the branched off branches instead of the main branches.

I partially agree with @MicroVirus' comment above, but I think this is only important for the main branches (mostly *master*, in your case *staging*, ...), which should be stable and not change its history, as other people may already have cloned and checked them out and most importantly, base their work off them.
For feature or development branches, which are work in progress anyway, it's ok to change the history.

**EDIT**

Sidenote: In general it's a better workflow to regularly rebase your *develop* branch to *staging* if you need newer commits from the *staging* branch instead of cherry-picking.